# I'm trying to handle exeption with powershell on Azure DevOps - try{./app.exe} catch{ Write-Output $PSItem.Exception; exit(1)}

Tags: powershell

When building a pipeline in Azure DevOps I am trying to use in powershell

```
try{./app.exe} catch{ Write-Output $PSItem.Exception; exit(1)}
```

and after app execution it should return true (interrupt a pipe step) or false (mark successfully complete).

What am I doing wrong? Pipeline ends sucessfully all times.

Comment: What if you just used `Start-Process "app.exe" -ErrorAction "Stop"`?

Comment: Thank you @codaamok. Problem resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable is set to `Stop` in the current scope:

```
function Test-ExeInvocationFailure {

  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

  try {
    $null = ./app.exe
  }
  catch {
    return $true
  }

  return $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0
}
```